# Font-Monterrat-Black didnt function

Tags: html, css

Need some help on why the font that was downloaded from Fonts.google didn't render as it should
the font is "Montserrat-Black" but the website stayed with the default font. 
Thank you for your assistance

I did the following;

1. Copied and pasted the HREF link to the Header;

2. Coded the  "Montserrat-Black",  to the CSS, (shown below)

But text stayed at default.

```
h1 {

font-family: "Montserrat-Black";

font-size: 3rem;

line-height: 1.5;
}
```

3. Also, I ran the HTML thru a code validator: RESULTS ARE:

   Error: Bad value https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900|Ubuntu&display=swap for attribute HREF on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.
   From line 8, column 3; to line 8, column 112
   **title>`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900|Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">**`

Comment: Following the error message, please try to url encode the pipe character: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900%7CUbuntu&display=swap

Answer (score 1):

Use this link in the HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this CSS:

```
h1 {
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-size: 3rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-weight: 900;
}
```

In the CSS, I added `font-weight: 900;` and changed `Montserrat-Black` to `Montserrat` because that's how it works. Montserrat-Black is actually Montserrat with `font-weight: 900;`

Answer (score 0):

have you imported the font in the css if you haven't you need to import it because it doesn't have a source to find the font file

if you have the font file you can use this:

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: Montserrat;
 src: url(../font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf)
}
```

if you don't have the font file locally you can use this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
```